# Find duplicate rows and delete specific one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I got table like this:

```
Col1 | Col2
AAA  | 1
BBB  | X
AAA  | X
CCC  | 1
```

I want to find duplicates based on Col1. Then i want to leave the row which has 'X' in Col2 and delete the other one.

I found how to find the duplicates:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3=count(*)
INTO holdkey
FROM t1
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

But this example further shows only how to delete identical rows and not how to choose one.

btw, this is mssql2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table is called test, this should work.  I just tried it :-)

```
DELETE From test WHERE Col1 IN(
SELECT Col1 FROM test 
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
AND Col2 = '1'
```

Comment: You probably want AND Col2 <> 'X', but that works for your example :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use of updatable CTEs and window functions:

```
with todelete as (
      select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
      from t1
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt > 1 and col2 <> 'X';
```

Comment: Im getting Incorrect syntax error. Forgot to mention this is server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE tbl1 FROM t1 AS tbl1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 tbl2.col1 
    FROM t1 AS tbl2
    WHERE tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
    GROUP BY tbl2.col1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
WHERE tbl1.col2 != 'X'
```

Comment: Getting: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation

Comment: Yea I had brackets instead of parenthesis. Try it now.

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." Like i mentioned this is server 2000, might due that?

Answer (score 0):

Can there be a case where Col1 duplicates but neither instance has col2='x'. If you have this case you will lose that value from the table.

```
select col1 
into tmp
from t1 
group by t1 
having count(*)>1;


delete from t1 
where col1 in (select col1 from tmp) 
 and col2<>'X';

Drop table tmp;
```